# ¿Puede un usuario darse una recompensa a sí mismo?

Tags: soporte, recompensas

He encontrado este caso en particular en el cual un usuario parece que se da la recompensa a sí mismo.

No sé si esto es posible, éticamente no debería serlo ya que genera ventaja al ganar puntos. Si estoy equivocado, por favor alguien que me explique en detalle si esto es posible.

Comparto el enlace de la pregunta: [¿Como eliminar una fila de un ASPxGridView?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/455580/como-eliminar-una-fila-de-un-aspxgridview)

Comment: El usuario, se autorespondio y acepto su respuesta, aceptar una respuesta a una pregunta hecha por uno mismo no da puntos, por otra parte un usuario no puede darse votos a el mismo

Answer (score 9):

Empecemos por partes. El usuario no se da una recompensa a si mismo. Si este fuera el caso (que no es posible, el sistema no te deja hacer eso), entonces tampoco se da nada, porque el usuario uso su propia reputación para poner la recompensa.

En este caso, la recompensa se va a perder.. y el usuario perderá esos puntos de reputación.

Cito:
"Can I award a bounty to my own answer?
No. This used to be possible, but it has been disabled. The +50 (or whatever bounty amount was allocated) award button simply won't show beside your own answers.

(On past bounties awarded to one's own answers, the user would not get the reputation back, and the bounty would be displayed as +0, “this answer has been awarded bounty worth 0 reputation”.)" [fuente](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/141717)

Luego, contestar tu propia pregunta no solo es bueno, es buenísimo y no solo lo aceptamos, si no que lo promovemos!!!! [mira aca](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Por lo tanto, no hay nada malo en todo lo que paso.. salvo que el usuario perdió 50 puntos de reputación que nadie le va a devolver.

Answer (score 5):

Del Centro de ayuda en [¿Qué es una recompensa? ¿Cómo puedo iniciar una?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty):

> ##### ¿Cómo se concede una recompensa?
>
> El período de duración de una recompensa es de 7 días. Las recompensas deben tener una duración mínima de al menos 1 día. Una vez que la recompensa ha finalizado, hay un período de gracia de 24 horas para otorgarla manualmente. Simplemente haz clic en el botón de otorgar recompensa que hay junto a cada respuesta para otorgarla permanentemente al autor de la misma. (**No puedes otorgar una recompensa a tu propia respuesta**.)

Por tanto, *no* puede darse la recompensa a sí mismo y, por tanto, no lo hizo.

Answer (score 1):

Si con *"genera ventaja"* te refieres a que el usuario pueda generar reputación "de la nada" para su beneficio, entonces no tienes porqué preocuparte ya qué los "puntos" de la recompensa provienen de la misma reputación del usuario. Por lo tanto, auto responder su pregunta lo que haría sería devolverle la reputación que "gastó" al iniciar la recompensa. Para mayor [información](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty).

Por otro lado creo que autoresponderse una pregunta es de beneficio para el sitio mientras aporte información que pueda ayudar a otro usuario que tenga el mismo problema, mira [este enlace de la sección de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).